# Create new Windows command in Python

Tags: python, process, cmd

How can I create a new cmd window, using `subprocess.Popen`?

I've tried with:

```
process = subprocess.Popen('C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

but this isn't working the way I want to. It starts a new cmd, but inside the calling window.

I can't use `os.system('cmd')` because this method doens't provide an input handle.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.

```
process = subprocess.Popen('C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simpler

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["start", "cmd"], shell=True)
```